# How to handle the set of objects that represents a context?

Tags: php, mysql, architecture, code-organization

How can I handle the situation when exists the context that represents a collection of arbitrary objects?

This context can be created by code like this:

```
$context = new Context();
$context->add(new Category($current_category_id));
$context->add(new Filter($one_filter_id));
$context->add(new Filter($another_filter_id));
```

My question is how to store the context in a relational database and then to map the context object created by the code the next time the code is executed on the record in the table?

I think that I can have a method of a context instance named like "checksum" that will produce a checksum string for the content of the context at any time and use this as a primary id.

Is there a common design pattern to achieve this?

Comment: This is very similar in intent to a web session. The requirement is the same i.e. a context that represents a collection of arbitrary objects. The only difference is the persistence method?

Comment: It is similar only by its data structure. Concerning sessions we have a cookie with a random generated id of a session which identifies the set of objects on a server-side. In my case there is necessary to map the table record to the set of objects using objects that included to the set, because there is a no id at client-side or somewhere else.